# update on a subdoc with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am using mongoose. I simply want to update the subscription status for a particular user subscription.

I have the following database structure:

```
var subscriptionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({                 
            subscription_id            :String,
            start:                      String,
            status:                     String,
            user_id:                    String,
            cancel_at_period_end:       String,
            current_period_start:       String,
            current_period_end:         String,
            ended_at:                   String,
            trial_start:                String,
            trial_end:                  String,
            canceled_at:                String,
            quantity:                   String,
            application_fee_percent:    String,
            discount:                   String,
            tax_percent:                String   
        });



// define the schema for our user model
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
stripe           : {
    stripe_customer_id: String,
    default_card:       String          
},
subscriptions: [subscriptionSchema],
cards: [cardSchema]
});
```

I have this code, it doesnt throw any errors but it does not update the status either. Any ideas? Subscription_id is unique to the record. A user might have multiple subscriptions

```
var user = require('./models/user');

user.update(
   { 
    'subscriptions.subscription_id':updatedsubscription_id
    },
   {
      status: updatedsubscription_status
   },
   { upsert: true }, function(err, doc){
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    return console.log('updated the subscription in db');
}
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When updating an array element by id, you can use the [`$` positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) in your update object to represent the index of the element matched by the query:

```
user.update(
   {
     'subscriptions.subscription_id':updatedsubscription_id
   },
   {
      'subscriptions.$.status': updatedsubscription_status
   },
   function(err, count){
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      return console.log('updated the subscription in db');
   }
);
```